# RecyclerView shows Strings but not Images

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a SQLite database and want to search Items thorugh DB and then showing the items on recyclerView. Everything looking fine but recyclerView not showing the pictures, But somehow It shows the Strings
[image: Here is the picture of result]

Normally pictures I saved inside the SQLite as BLOB should be displayed on the left.

Here is SearchFragment (Where I make the search and start recyclerView to display items)

```
public class SearchFragment extends Fragment {

Button searchbutton;
EditText editText;
View v;
Cursor cursor;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_search, container, false);
    addListenerOnButton(v);
    return v;
}

private void addListenerOnButton(View v) {
    searchbutton = v.findViewById(R.id.searchfragment_button);
    editText = v.findViewById(R.id.searchfragment_edittext);
    searchbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String keystring = editText.getText().toString();
            if(keystring.isEmpty())
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),R.string.empty_search ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                new FoodQuery().execute(keystring);
        }
    });
}

//Place I start the search on background
private class FoodQuery extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String [] keys) {
        String name_col;
        DietAppDatabaseHelper daDBHelper;
        SQLiteDatabase daDB;
        daDBHelper = new DietAppDatabaseHelper(getContext());
        try {
            daDB = daDBHelper.getReadableDatabase();
            if (Locale.getDefault().getLanguage() == "tr")
                name_col = "name_tr";
            else
                name_col = "name_eng";
            String query = "SELECT * FROM food_data WHERE " //Query here
                    + name_col + " LIKE ?" ;
            cursor = daDB.rawQuery(query, new String[]{"%" + keys[0] + "%"});
            viewResults(name_col);
            daDB.close();
        } catch (SQLiteException e){
            Log.d("SearchFragment", "doInBackground: " + e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

private void viewResults(String lang) {
    int name_col = -1;         //For language issues not important
    if(lang == "name_tr")
        name_col = 1;
    else if(lang == "name_eng")
        name_col = 2;

    ArrayList<String> tmpnames = new ArrayList<>();    //I put pictures to byte[] and names to String Arraylist here
    ArrayList<byte[]> tmppictures = new ArrayList<>();
    if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
        tmpnames.add(cursor.getString(name_col));
        tmppictures.add(cursor.getBlob(5));
        while(cursor.moveToNext()){
            tmpnames.add(cursor.getString(name_col));
            tmppictures.add(cursor.getBlob(5));
        }
    }
    else {
        Looper.prepare();
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), R.string.no_food_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //To prevent empty search
    }
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                RecyclerView recyclerView = v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
                SearchResultAdapter adapter = new SearchResultAdapter(getContext(), tmppictures, tmpnames);
                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
            }
        });
}
}
```

Layout File of SearchFragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".fragments.SearchFragment"
android:id="@+id/fragment_search">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/searchfragment_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:text="@string/nav_search"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/searchfragment_edittext"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/searchfragment_button"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="124dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is the adapter

```
public class SearchResultAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchResultAdapter.ViewHolder>{

private ArrayList<byte[]> foodimages;
private ArrayList<String> foodnames;
private Context context;

public SearchResultAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<byte[]> foodimages, ArrayList<String> foodnames) {
    this.foodimages = new ArrayList<>(foodimages);
    this.foodnames = new ArrayList<>(foodnames);
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.search_result_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.foodname.setText(foodnames.get(position));
    holder.foodimage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodimages.get(position), 0, foodimages.size()));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return foodnames.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView foodimage;
    TextView foodname;
    RelativeLayout parentLayout;
    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        foodimage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_seacrh_image);
        foodname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_search_name);
        parentLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.search_item);
    }
}
}
```

Lastly, the layout of my item to use in recyclerView

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="15dp"
android:id="@+id/search_item">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/food_seacrh_image"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/food_search_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/food_seacrh_image"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/food_seacrh_image"
    android:layout_marginStart="30dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the problem could be the line:

```
holder.foodimage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodimages.get(position), 0, foodimages.size()));
```

Should probably be:

```
holder.foodimage.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(foodimages.get(position), 0, foodimages.get(position).size));
```

The third param on `decodeByteArray` should be the length (in bytes) of the image, you are passing in the actual number of images.

Comment: You are right, thank you so much. Also foodimages.get(position) is a byte array, therefore it does not have size function. Used length instead and worked.